# How do I get my code to display correctly when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

For some reason I can't get my code to disply correctly when asking a question. Instead of displying as a block, it's one long line. Here is a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639131/how-can-i-reposition-an-entry-form-and-button-correctly-on-a-background-image) I asked where you can see what I'm talking about. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the entire code section and then click the Code button `{ }` in the edit box tool bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you put 4 spaces of indentation before every line of code, you will correctly see it as code in the posted answer/question.

You can also see this on the right hand side of the browser while editing in the `How to Format` section.